# Date parameter in query designer SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Every time I enter in a date parameter to test a query in the query designer in SSRS, I get an error "ORA-01843: not a valid month".

I typically am testing a date in the following formats:
1/1/2017
1-1-2017
30/12/2016

And I still get the error.  How does it want me to input the date? I am losing my mind.

Comment: If you are inputting the date as 30/12/2016 are you changing the locale on the Report Property to English UK so that it knows the month is first?

Comment: I'm just trying anything @Mmcgowa3.. I must just be missing something.  I set the parameter to be a date/time type.  Do I need to cast it as anything?

Comment: The format of 1/1/2017 should work when type is Text or Date/Time. MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh - you're connecting to an Oracle database.

The date must be cast as a date.

Use:

```
TO_DATE('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: Note: This does not work when putting it in as a parameter when executing a query in the Query Designer. It may work fine in the SQL, but not as a parameter. Anyone know of a way to pass a date as a parameter?